How to define custom file type in Swift?
I am trying import a custom file type of "xyz", there fore I made this code, the app does not let me chose xyz file also I have this warning:
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        Button("Read xyz project") {
            isPresented.toggle()
        }
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $isPresented,
            allowedContentTypes: [UTType(importedAs: "xyz")],
            onCompletion: { result in
                do {
                    let fileURL = try result.get()
                    print("Selected file: \(fileURL)")
      
                } catch {
                    print("Failed to read file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

also in plist with this:

I cannot follow other answers, because apple keep changing ui for plist, here what i could do by myself.

Just below "Document Types", there are "Exported Type Identifiers" and "Imported Type Identifiers". If you are using UTType(importedAs:), you should be putting your identifier in the latter.

@Sweeper: I did that did not helped

Well from your screenshot you put it in "Exported Type Identifiers". But if you want to use UTType(importedAs: "public.xyz"), you should put it in "Imported Type Identifiers".

Also the identifier you wrote in there ("xyz") doesn't match the identifier you wrote in code ("public.xyz").

You are right! I was following an answer, and got mixed up, I corrected, now I can select the file, but I have issue of "Type "xyz" was expected to be imported in the Info.plist of type file.app, but it was exported instead."

Put it in "Imported Type Identifiers" then! Your second screenshot still shows that you have it in "Exported Type Identifiers".

Oh my god, I am total, idiot! thanks

I see Icon Image, Icon Text, Icon Fill, Is it means the file type xyz going to have a icon in my mac outside the app, also I cannot delete "Imported Type Identif.." for xyz, if I want delete it from plist, there is no delete option

"Is it means the file type xyz going to have an icon in my mac outside the app" Yes. You can always delete it directly from Info.plist. It should be obvious what key to delete.

Do you know where and how I can give the icon and photo for xyz, is there a place to learn. thanks a lot for your help

I'd recommend reading the old documentation on this. The examples are in Objective C, but it explains the concepts very well. You'll want to conform your new UTI to an established UTI like public.text, public.image, com.apple.bundle, etc.). You'll probably also want to fill in the Extensions: field with xyz, to associate your UTI to files with an .xyz extension.
